# Базу данных в оперативную память

Tags: c++, mysql

На одном компе стоит *MySQL*. Нужно экспортировать оттуда таблицу и перенести на другой комп.
На втором компе есть прога, которая проводит расчеты с данными таблицы. Нужно как-то эту таблицу полностью закинуть в оперативку (да нужна вся сразу).
Пробовал ставить на втором компе *MySQL* и создавать таблицу *memory*, но не получается, то ли таблица слишком большая (>1млн строк), то ли я нечего не понял.
В общем, в итоге нужно иметь в оперативке структурированные данные (типа двумерного массива), чтобы можно было обращаться к ним.

Как такое реализовать?

Пробовал делать запрос на выборку всех данных таблицы из проги к *MySQL* базе и поэлементно переводить в двумерный массив, но получается слишком долго.

Comment: _На втором компе есть прога, которая проводит расчеты с данными таблицы._ Я не понял - эту программу вы пишете и оптимизируете, или это стороннее приложение, недоступное к корректировке? Больше похоже на первое - а тогда почему просто не получить эти данные в массив (или коллекцию, или даже пусть и рекордсет), определённый в программе, зачем лишние посредники? PS. Миллион записей - это в общем может быть и мало, и много... а зависит это от среднего размера одной записи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, точнее поясните в чем проблема: в корости, памяти мало. Раскажите больше про общую задачу, насколько часто обработку нужно делать (один раз, периодически, в реальном времени)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

- на первом компе сделать экспорт таблице в текстовом виде
- передать текстовой файл на второй комп
- преобразовать текстовой файл в бинарный
- в программе выделить память под двумерный массив
- бинарный файл загрузить по указателю на двумерный массив

Для ускорения обработки файлов (экспорт таблицы, преобразование в бинарный) - желательно использовать RAM-диск, чтобы избавится от тормозов дисковой подсистемы.

Если к данным в оперативной памяти нужен не прямой доступ, а средства поиска, тогда можно попробовать SQLite с хранением файла БД на том же RAM-диске.